# How to export a datatable to a previous created PDF file while specifying a page to do that? (or creating a new page)

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, itext, export

I have the following task to complete: based on a dataset, I have to fill a PDF file's form fields using `itextsharp` while also exporting the said dataset on a table "format" so it could go on the second page of said PDF file.

[image: Here is the PDF file wich has the form fields]

The table will go below the title on the second page wich is landscape-oriented. But I'm also accepting a solution/hint which involves deleting the second page and create-write one by code-side.

This is by far the work I've made

```
class PDFFormFiller
{
    public void FillForm(UInt32 tipo, string campo, string numeroConsultas, DataSet ds)
    {
        // I use this on another specific case, dont bother with it.
        string data = System.DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();

        switch (tipo)
        {

        case 1: // Medical report
            {
                // Get the previous created pdf file...
                string pdfTemplate = Application.StartupPath + "\\Templates\\Template Medico.pdf";
                // ...and generate a new one with the filled forms and the table
                string newFile = Application.StartupPath + "\\Relatórios\\Relatório Médico_" + data + ".pdf";

                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

                AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                // Form fields filling by the arguments up there, dont bother with'em
                pdfFormFields.SetField("data", data);
                pdfFormFields.SetField("medico_nome", campo);
                pdfFormFields.SetField("numero_consultas", numeroConsultas);

                // Table build
                int numColumns = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
                PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(numColumns);
                datatable.DefaultCell.Padding = 0;
                datatable.WidthPercentage = 100; // percentage
                datatable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                float[] columnWidths = {20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 20, 20, 20, 20};
                datatable.SetWidths(columnWidths);

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        datatable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE;
                        datatable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                        Phrase phrase = new Phrase(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9));
                        datatable.AddCell(phrase);
                    }
                }

                // The table code goes here

                // Final Message
                string relatorio = ("Relatório para o médico" + pdfFormFields.GetField("medico_nome") + "gerado com sucesso na pasta Relatórios");
                MessageBox.Show(relatorio);

                // Form flattening set to true to avoid
                // further edition of the form fields on the file created
                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

                // Clode the pdf stamper
                pdfStamper.Close();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: forgot to say that any help will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damm, solved with two lines....

```
                        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                datatable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE;
                                datatable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                Phrase phrase = new Phrase(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9));
                                datatable.AddCell(phrase);
                            }
                        }

+                        PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(2);

+                        datatable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 70.0f, 400.0f, content);
```

Not to say that i had to search the entire internet to sort this thing out..